# UnicodeEncodeErrors while using DictWriter for utf-8

Tags: unicode, utf-8, python-2.7, export-to-csv

I am trying to write a dictionary containing utf-8 strings to a CSV. I'm following the instructions from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838605/python-dictwriter-writing-utf-8-encoded-csv-files). However, despite meticulously encoding and decoding these utf-8 strings, I am getting a UnicodeEncodeErrors involving 'ascii' sets.

I have a list of dictionaries which contain strings and ints as values related to changes to Wikipedia articles. The list below corresponds to [this change](http://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?diff=121862749&oldid=prev), for example:

```
edgelist = [{'articleName': 'Barack Obama', 'editorName': 'Schonbrunn', 'revID': '121844749', 'bytesAdded': '183'}, 
{'articleName': 'Barack Obama', 'editorName': 'Eep\xc2\xb2', 'revID': '121862749', 'bytesAdded': '107'}]
```

The problem is `list[1]['editorName']`. It has type `'str'` and `el[1]['editorName'].decode('utf-8')` is `u'Eep\xb2'`

The code I am attempting is:

```
_ENCODING = 'utf-8'
def dictToCSV(edgelist,output_file):
    with codecs.open(output_file,'wb',encoding=_ENCODING) as f:
        w = csv.DictWriter(f,sorted(edgelist[0].keys()))
        w.writeheader()
        for d in edgelist:
            for k,v in d.items():
                if type(v) == int:
                    d[k]=str(v).encode(_ENCODING)
            w.writerow({k:v.decode(_ENCODING) for k,v in d.items()})
```

This returns:

```
dictToCSV(edgelist,'test2.csv')
File "csv_to_charts.py", line 129, in dictToCSV
w.writerow({k:v.decode(_ENCODING,'ignore') for k,v in d.items()})
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/csv.py", line 148, in writerow
return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xb2' in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Other permutations such as swapping decode for encode or nothing in the final problematic line also return errors:

1. `w.writerow({k:v.encode(_ENCODING) for k,v in d.items()})` returns `'UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 56: ordinal not in range(128)`
2. `w.writerow({k:v for k,v in d.items()})` returns `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc2 in position 56: ordinal not in range(128)`
3. Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3285578/csv-dictwriter-unicode-and-utf-8), I changed `with codecs.open(output_file,'wb',encoding=_ENCODING) as f:` to `with open(output_file,'wb') as f:` and still receive the same error.

Excluding the list element(s) or the keys containing this problematic string, the script works fine otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just edited your code as follows and the csv was written successfully.

```
from django.utils.encoding import smart_str
import csv

def dictToCSV(edgelist, output_file):
    f = open(output_file, 'wb')
    w = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames=sorted(edgelist[0].keys()))
    w.writeheader()
    for d in edgelist:
        w.writerow(dict(k=smart_str(v)) for k, v in d.items())
    f.close()
```

Copy the Django code and customize it to your need.

Answer (score 0):

A strict interpretation of ASCII encoding only allows ordinals 0-127.  Any value outside that range is not ASCII by definition.  Since both \xc2 & \xb2 have ordinals higher than 127, they cannot be interpreted as ASCII.

*I'm not a Python user*, the [RFC for CSV](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) mentions ASCII as a common usage but defines an optional 'charset' parameter for the MIME type; I wonder if the writer you're using also might have an 'encoding' setting?

Answer (score 0):

Your strings are already in UTF-8, and DictWriter doesn't work with `codecs.open`.  Following [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5838605/python-dictwriter-writing-utf-8-encoded-csv-files) example:

```
# coding: utf-8
import csv

edgelist = [
    {'articleName': 'Barack Obama', 'editorName': 'Schonbrunn', 'revID': '121844749', 'bytesAdded': '183'},
    {'articleName': 'Barack Obama', 'editorName': 'Eep\xc2\xb2', 'revID': '121862749', 'bytesAdded': '107'}]

with open('out.csv','wb') as f:
    f.write(u'\ufeff'.encode('utf8')) # BOM (optional...Excel needs it to open UTF-8 file properly)
    w = csv.DictWriter(f,sorted(edgelist[0].keys()))
    w.writeheader()
    for d in edgelist:
        w.writerow(d)
```

Output:

```
articleName,bytesAdded,editorName,revID
Barack Obama,183,Schonbrunn,121844749
Barack Obama,107,Eep²,121862749
```

Note, you can use `'editorName': 'Eep²'` directly instead of `'editorName': 'Eep\xc2\xb2'`.  The byte string will be UTF-8-encoded per the `# coding: utf-8` and if you save the source file in UTF-8.